# Why "Reference to undefined global `Moduletest'" in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I wrote

```
let fact x = 
let result = ref 1 in
for i = 1 to x do
    result := !result * i;
    Printf.printf "%d %d %d\n" x i !result;
done;
!result;;
```

in a file named "Moduletest.ml", and

```
val fact : int -> int
```

in a file named "Moduletest.mli".

But, why don't they work?

When I tried to use in ocaml,

```
Moduletest.fact 3
```

it told me:

```
Error: Reference to undefined global `Moduletest'
```

What's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you "use in ocaml"? Using `#use` or `#load` or from an another file? How are you compiling? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your code. I imagine you are using `#use`, this just enters the contents of the file into the toplevel, and thus does not have the surrounding implicit module name (by file).

Answer (score 11):

OCaml toplevel is linked only with a standard library. There're several options on how to make other code visible to it:

1. copy-pasting
2. evaluating from the editor
3. loading files `#use` directive
4. making custom toplevel
5. loading with ocamlfind

## Copy-pasting

This self-describing, you just copy code from some source and paste it into toplevel. Don't forget that toplevel won't evaluate your code until you add `;;`

## Evaluating from the editor

Where the editor is of course Emacs... Well, indeed it can be any other capable editor, like vim for example.  This method is an elaboration of the previous, where the editor is actually responsible for copying and pasting the code for you. In Emacs you can evaluate the whole file with `C-c C-b` command, or you can narrow it to a selected area with `C-c C-r`, and the most granular is to use `C-c C-e`, i.e., evaluate an expression. Although it is slightly buggy.

## Loading with `#use` directive.

This directive accepts a filename, and it will essentially copy and paste the code from the file. Notice, that it won't create a file-module for you/ For example, if you have file `test.ml` with this contents:

```
(* file test.ml *)
let sum x y = x + y
```

then loading it with the `#use` directive, will actually bring to your scope, `sum` value:

```
# #use "test.ml";;
# let z = sum 2 2
```

You mustn't to qualify `sum` with `Test.`, because no `Test` module is actually created. `#use` directive merely copies the contents of the file to the toplevel. Nothing more.

## Making custom toplevels

You can create your own toplevel with your code compiled in. It is an advanced theme, so I will skip it.

## Loading libraries with `ocamlfind`

`ocamlfind` is a tool that allows you to find and load libraries, installed on your system, into your toplevel. By default, toplevel is not linked with any code except standard library. Even, not all parts of the library are actually linked, e.g., `Unix` module is not available, and needed to be loaded explicitly. There're primitive directives that can load any library, like `#load` and `#include`, but they are not for a casual user, especially if you have excellent `ocamlfind` at your disposal. Before using it, you need to load it, since it is also not available by default. The following command, will load `ocamlfind` and add few new directives:

```
# #use "topfind";;
```

In a process of loading it will show you a little hint on how to use it. The most interesting directive, that is added is `#require`. It accepts a library name, and loads (i.e., links) its code into toplevel:

```
# #require "unix";;
```

This will load a `unix` library. If you're not sure, about the name of the library you can always view all libraries with a `#list` command. The `#require` directive is clever and it will automatically load all dependencies of the library.

If you do not want to type all this directives every time you start OCaml top-level, then you cam create `.ocamlinit` file in your home directory, and put them there. This file will be loaded automatically on a top-level startup.

Comment: My prof told me I should compile and write this in cmd or terminal : ocaml moduletest.cmo. And finally, I found it works.

Comment: yep, other than interactive top-level, OCaml has a compiler =)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and it looks fine. You should "load" it from the OCaml toplevel (launched from the same directory as your `.ml` and `.mli` files) in the following way:

```
# #use "Moduletest.ml";;
val fact : int -> int = <fun>
# fact 4;;
4 1 1
4 2 2
4 3 6
4 4 24
- : int = 24
```